# Alternative to "overflow:scroll;" to create a permanent vertical scrollbar in a div?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a div in which I need a permanent vertical scrollbar. Sometimes the scrollbar will be needed because the div will contain excess content and other times it will not be needed but I want the appearance to be consistent - even when there is not excess content in the div I want it to contain a scrollbar. I tried this but it doesn't add a scrollbar when there is no excess content:

```
div#collection
{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 0 0 0;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

I also tried increasing the height to 200% (html and body are set to 100%) but then the whole page scrolls - which is not what I want - I want the div alone to scroll while the rest of the page remains where it is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: overflow: scroll is what you want ... we'd have to see the rest of the story to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put a wrapper container within the div, and set it to height:101%.

Comment: Never seen this fix before. Nice find :)

Answer (score 3):

Most newer browsers support CSS3's overflow-x and overflow-y:

```
div.verticalscroll {
    overflow: auto; /* For browsers that can't do overflow-y */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Controls overflow on the y-axis */
}
```

See http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: But th W3C validator won't unless you specifically tell it that you are using CSS3

Comment: The validator is just a tool. Overflow-x and -y are in the spec and the browsers, so I can't see a problem with using them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Give the top container a height and an overflow-y: scroll, then have a sub container for the rest of the content that has a min-height set to be a couple pixels taller than the height of the container.

```
div#collection
{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 0 0 0;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: white;
    overflow:scroll;
}

div#sub {
    min-height: 402px;
}

<div id="collection">
    <div id="sub">
        Content goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto` it will do what you want

Comment: auto only drops in a scroll bar if the content overflows.  Sounds like he wants it there permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Try overflow-y:scroll ... that would do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

this can help you